# Where does a file sit when part of an HTTP POST request?

Tags: http-post

Where does a file sit when attached to an HTTP POST request?  Does it sit in memory somewhere, on the recipient's web server?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the http response object so should be totally in memory, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the file are included in the body of the HTTP request.

It gets transmitted over the network to the HTTP server.

The server then does whatever it wants with the data.